# android studio - login register with php mysql (server connection failed)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I can't input data on my server
I'm using wampp server and every time I run my project and input data, I'm always getting the following error `server connection failed`.

Can somebody please help me to resolve this issue?

**Below is my code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 protected EditText username;
 private EditText password;
 protected String enteredUsername;
 private final String serverUrl = "url server";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_field);
     password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_field);
     Button loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
     Button registerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register_button);

     loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             enteredUsername = username.getText().toString();
             String enteredPassword = password.getText().toString();

             if(enteredUsername.equals("") || enteredPassword.equals("")){
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or password must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 return;
             }
             if(enteredUsername.length() <= 1 || enteredPassword.length() <= 1){
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or password length must be greater than one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 return;
             }
             // request authentication with remote server4
             AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();
             asyncRequestObject.execute(serverUrl, enteredUsername, enteredPassword);
         }
     });

     registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
     });
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
     return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
     int id = item.getItemId();

     //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
         return true;
     }

     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

         HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
         HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
         HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

         HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
         HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

         String jsonResult = "";
         try {
             List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[1]));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[2]));
             httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
             HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
             jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return jsonResult;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
         System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
         if(result.equals("") || result == null){
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return;
         }
         int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
         if(jsonResult == 0){
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return;
         }
         if(jsonResult == 1){
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("USERNAME", enteredUsername);
             intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "You have been successfully login");
             startActivity(intent);
         }
     }
     private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
         String rLine = "";
         StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         try {
             while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 answer.append(rLine);
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return answer;
     }
 }
 private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

     JSONObject resultObject = null;
     int returnedResult = 0;
     try {
         resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
         returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return returnedResult;
 } 
}
```

**user.php**

```
 <?php

include_once 'db.php';

class User{

    private $db;
    private $db_table = "users";

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new DbConnect();
    }

    public function isLoginExist($username, $password){     

        $query = "select * from " . $this->db_table . " where username = '$username' AND password = '$password' Limit 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
            return true;
        }       
        mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
        return false;       
    }

    public function createNewRegisterUser($username, $password, $email){

        $query = "insert into users (username, password, email, created_at, updated_at) values ('$username', '$password', '$email', NOW(), NOW())";
        $inserted = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);
        if($inserted == 1){
            $json['success'] = 1;                                   
        }else{
            $json['success'] = 0;
        }
        mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
        return $json;
    }

    public function loginUsers($username, $password){

        $json = array();
        $canUserLogin = $this->isLoginExist($username, $password);
        if($canUserLogin){
            $json['success'] = 1;
        }else{
            $json['success'] = 0;
        }
        return $json;
    }

}
?>
```

*index.php*

```
<?php

require_once 'androidlogin/user.php';

$username = "";
$password = "";
$email = "";
echo "hello";
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}
if(isset($_POST['password'])){
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}

// Instance of a User class
$userObject = new User();

// Registration of new user
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email)){
    $hashed_password = md5($password);
    $json_registration = $userObject->createNewRegisterUser($username, $hashed_password, $email);

    echo json_encode($json_registration);
}

// User Login
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && empty($email)){
    $hashed_password = md5($password);  
    $json_array = $userObject->loginUsers($username, $hashed_password);

    echo json_encode($json_array);
}

?>
```

*db.php*

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';

class DbConnect{


    private $connect;


    public function __construct(){

        $this->connect = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno($this->connect))
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();  
        }
    }

    public function getDb(){

        return $this->connect;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your url is literally "server url" which makes no sense. Please understand what you are doing before you copy someone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. You cannot use wamp server because the PHP files are not exposed to the web. In a simpler sense, the PHP files you coded are only available on your PC/Laptop and are not accessible to the mobile application. You may be able to connect if you are debugging using an emulator, however once you install your app on an actual device, there would be no connection to the server.

I recommend you choose one of the following online hosting services and upload your files and database (which you created in WAMP). You will need to obviously change the IP address you are connecting to from the code you posted above. This will let you connect to the server and login successfully. There are several free hosting services out there, most of which have a 99% uptime. So you won't have any issues with connectivity. Such hosting services are offered by awardspace, freewebhostingeu or 000webhost. Any of these will help you get the job done.

Alteratively you can expose your PHP files to the web, so that it is accessible from your device. If you have IIS installed, you can copy your website content to the `C:\inetpub\www` folder. This would expose (make it available on the web) your site to anyone knowing the url. You can also use [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere/) to help you. This option is a more advanced one, however it will help you get an idea of how websites are published if you are up for the challenge.

I have also found an issue in your code when returning the response through PHP. Your code returns a `org.json.JSONException`. This is because the value returned from the PHP script is not in valid JSON format. (It simply returns hello) Hence in the `index.php` file, amend the registration of a new user code in this way:

```
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email)){
    $hashed_password = md5($password);
    $json_registration = $userObject->createNewRegisterUser($username, $hashed_password, $email);
     if ($json_registration) {

            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["user"]["name"] = $json_registration["username"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $json_registration["email"];

            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {

            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
}
```

This returns the actual data from the database back to the app.

You need to do the same with the login script:

```
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && empty($email)){
    $hashed_password = md5($password);  
    $json_login = $userObject->loginUsers($username, $hashed_password);

    if ($json_login) {
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $json_login["Username"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $json_login["email"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

}
```

I may also recommend a couple of changes to your code style, to make a neater project.

- Use a different file name than `index.php`, simply because this is
  the default landing page of the side. I'd rather rename it to
  `Register.php` for example.
- Take away the code to login from the `index.php` file and add it to a
  separate file called `Login.php`. Don't forget that you need to call
  the connection string and the `User.php` class in this script too, to
  make sure it connects to the correct database.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for answering my question sir, i will try your suggestion :)

Comment: i have uploaded to hosting ,and the problem now every i register always show invalid username or password or email. please help me sir :(

Comment: Can you please include your code for PHP here please?

Comment: all php file or index.php?

Comment: please help me sir

Comment: so how i can change my old connection in android code, with correct code??

Comment: done i use url domain, but still error. i dont know why

Comment: yes i upload my php file in hosting and i use url for android code, but if i register always show invalid username or password or email.

Comment: this my hosting url : androiddinsos.esy.es

Comment: maybe, can i send my project php and android code to you??please help me sir :(

Comment: i change new user register and user login in index.php, but still the same, show invalid username or password or email :(